# How to select a option by order in a list box?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

In my first coding project, I try to make a robot that fills formularies. I would like to choose the first option from the list without needing the value, just by the order in the list.

I have problems selecting options from a list. The list box has several names but the options are refined as you write the name. I've made the bot type the name, but I would like it to select the first option which is mandatory for the procedure.

Selecting by name is not an option, as I cannot know all the values before that I need to fill in the formulary.

**Options list and two options:**

```
<select id="form:nomeAutor:listbox" name="form:nomeAutor:listbox" class="list-itens-au " size="2" onblur="com.corejsf.inputLostFocus(this)" onkeyup="com.autocomplete.submitEnter(this, event);" style="display: inline; position: absolute; left: 124.765625px; top: 800.109375px" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange','form:nomeAutor','form:nomeAutor:nomeAutor form:nomeAutor:valueId')"> <option value="2147898">ADAIR JOSE PEREIRA DA ROCHA (Doutorado)</option>
    <option value="1585496">FERNANDA NADAI (Graduação)</option>
</select>
```

**My current code:**

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()  # Adiciona parênteses para chamar a função
    page.goto("https://sucupira.capes.gov.br/sucupira/coleta_online/producaoIntelectual/listaProducao.jsf")
    page.click("a[id='buttonAcessoCapes']")
    page.fill("input[name='login']",'00000000')
    page.fill("input[name='senha']",'00000000')
    page.click("button[id='textoBotao']")
    page.wait_for_timeout(2000)
    page.click("a[id='formPortais:portalCoordenadorPrograma']")
    page.click("a[id='formAbaColeta:btnProducaoIntelectual']")
    page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
    page.click("a[id='form:btnCadastrarProducao']")
    page.fill("input[id='form:nome']",'A relação entre a autoeficácia e o autoconceito em jovens atletas de futebol: uma revisão de escopo.')
    page.fill("input[id='form:anoPublicacao']",'2022')
    page.select_option("select[id='form:categoria']", 'Discente' )
    page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
    page.locator("input[name=\"form\\:nomeAutor\\:input\"]").type("ADAIR JOSÉ PEREIRA DA ROCH")
    page.wait_for_timeout(1000)
    page.locator("[id=\"form\\:nomeAutor\\:listbox\"]").select_option(all)
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Adicionar Autor").click(button="left")
    page.get_by_role("button", name="Próximo >>").click(button="left")
    page.wait_for_timeout(1000)
    page.locator("[id=\"form\\:tipo\"]").select_option("2")
    page.wait_for_timeout(1000)
    page.locator("[id=\"form\\:subtipo\"]").select_option("25")
    page.wait_for_timeout(2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select_option` method with an index parameter to select the first option in the list. Select the first option in the dropdown list without relying on the text value or waiting for a certain amount of time.

Here's a very short example:

```
page.locator("[id=\"form\\:nomeAutor\\:listbox\"]").select_option(index=0)
page.select_option("select[id='form:categoria']", 'Discente')
```

The first line selects the first option in the dropdown list named `"form:nomeAutor:listbox"` by ID, the other line selects the option with value `"Discente"` in the dropdown list with ID `"form:categoria"`.

See index at https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-select-option.

Comment: does'nt worked, i dont know why too, maybe the problem is with the page, i think it is made with java, i dont know

Comment: for more information, i have tried, but this seems to dont work and the line that should pick the option is just ignored, i think that's the best word, ignored